# VS.Net 2010 Entity Framework File Not Nesting Correctly

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4

I have a kind of silly question, but it's annoying me and I can't seem to find an answer. In Visual Studio 2010 I have several Entity Framework (v4) .edmx files. With one exception, they all nest their related designer.vb file so they only show as one file. I'm wondering if there is something I can do to make that last one nest like the others so it looks cleaner.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to edit your project file (i.e. csproj, vbproj) using Notepad and manually nest files. The syntax looks like:

```
<Compile Include="MyPath\MyFile.cs" />
<Compile Include="MyPath\MyNestedFile.cs">
  <DependentUpon>MyFile.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

Ofcourse, the extensions can be changed, as well as the paths.

[VS Commands](http://vscommands.com/) also has a feature to do this via Visual Studio, but I'm not sure it would work in your case.

More information can be found [here](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2006/11/nested-files-with-dependentupon-in.html) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpide/thread/f33c32df-14e4-4636-8c8e-c96f66666cb5).

Comment: Trouble is that I don't have a project file. I have a solution file, but I opened the website as a website (browse to folder) so there is no project file. (Even in the projects folder, there is only a .sln file.

It's not a really big deal, but is annoying...

Comment: @youtotiger - What does your sln file have in it?

Comment: a bunch of debug.AspNetcompiler settings, followed by a bunch of Release.AspNetCompiler settings in the project section, and then a global section that has a few other settings about which cpu to use.